# Laravel Inertia Vue Error with session flash message

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am currently working on a project in Laravel Inertia with a Jetstream starter pack that works with vue3.
I have to customize the login method. Basically, the logic will be if the user status is Inactive user will be prompted with an error using a session flash message.

**Here is my login method**

**App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(): void

{
    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    
    

        $user       = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $active     = User::where('email', $request->email)->where('status','1')->first();
        $inactive   = User::where('email', $request->email)->where('status','0')->first();
        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && $active ) {
                return $user;
        
            }
        else if
            ($user && $inactive) {
           $request->session()->flash('message', 'Your account is disabled. Please contact IT for support.');
            return false;
               

            }   
});
    $this->configurePermissions();

    Jetstream::deleteUsersUsing(DeleteUser::class);
}
```

This is my frontend view

**Login.vue**

```
    <div v-if="message"
        class="mb-4 text-sm font-bold tracking-wide border-l-4 border-red-700 text-center text-red-700 bg-red-100 px-2 py-4 rounded">
        {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
    </div>
```

according to the Inertia documentation the following code should display the message.
But I'm getting the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'flash')
> at setup (Login.vue:14:38)

Also Im getting a warning from vue

> app.js:18 [Vue warn]: Unhandled
> error during execution of setup function    at <Login jetstream=
> {canCreateTeams: false, canManageTwoFactorAuthentication: true,
> canUpdatePassword: true, canUpdateProfileInformation: true,
> hasEmailVerification: false, …} auth= {user: null} errorBags= []  ...
>
> > at <Inertia initialPage= {component: 'Auth/Login', props: {…}, url: '/', version: '1dcda246d0ee45f4b6bb48a97081b75f'}
> > initialComponent= {__name: 'Login', props: {…}, __hmrId: 'e4ebae0a',
> > setup: ƒ, render: ƒ, …} resolveComponent=fn  ... >    at

**Any expert can  help me with this error ?**

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is facing the same :

Here is the fix

I have updated the HandelInertiaRequests.php from the Middleware

**HandelInertiaRequests.php**

```
public function share(Request $request): array
{ 
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
   'flash' => 
        [
          'message' => session('message')  
        ]
    ]);
 }
```